# How to connect input to each deep layer?

Tags: python, keras

Here is the code I'm using to generate my model:

```
from tensorflow.keras import initializers
INNER_LAYER_SIZE=x.shape[1]
drouout_fraction=.0
#set_seeds(123456)

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=[x.shape[1],]),
    keras.layers.Dense(INNER_LAYER_SIZE, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform()),
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
    keras.layers.LeakyReLU(),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drouout_fraction),
])

for i in range(15):
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(int(INNER_LAYER_SIZE/2), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform()))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())    
    model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(drouout_fraction))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(y.shape[1], kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform()))
model.add(keras.layers.LeakyReLU())

model.compile(loss="mse", metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.1, momentum=0.25, nesterov=True#, decay=.001#/x.shape[0]
))#

last_loss=1

model.summary()
```

I would like to preserve processing between layers (e.g. Dropout, BatchNormalization, LeakyReLu) and connect the InputLayer to each deep layer, so that each deep layer is connected to previous layer and to input

I have tried writing it like

`model.add(keras.layers.Dense(int(INNER_LAYER_SIZE/2), kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomUniform())(input))`

This results in an error

I also have tried the `tf.concat([previous, input], axis=1)`, where previous would be previous item that was added to the model, for example, `LeakyReLU` or `Dropout`. This didn't work either.

What is the correct syntax to do what I want to do?

Comment: If you want to concatenate layers, you should use the Functional API, not the Sequential.

Comment: Yes, you cannot mix the Functional and Sequential APIs like that, it does not make sense, just use the Functional API for everything.